# Multiple if statements on one line

Tags: java, if-statement

How does a statement like this execute?

```
int x = 2, y = 3;

if (x != 0) if (x < 10) if (y < 10) {
    x++;
    y++;
    System.out.printf("X and Y are: %d, and %d", x, y);
}
```

Comment: You can put all that in one statement using the `&&` operator.

Comment: When in doubt, add curly braces to clarify.

Comment: "*How does a statement like this execute?*" It will not execute because it will not compile because of `System.out.println(x, y);`.

Comment: and also 1o  should be 10

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple 'If' statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523157/multiple-if-statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it could be compiled, it would get executed exactly like this:

```
if (x != 0) 
   if (x < 10) 
     if (y < 1o) {
        x++;
        y++;
        System.out.println(x, y);
     }
```

However, it's not very readable. You could improve its readability by using logical operators or proper line breaks and indentation.

Comment: System.out.println(x, y);??

Comment: @whiletrue You should be asking OP about it, not Andy.

Comment: @whiletrue - Good point. The "1o" would be another compiler error.

Comment: @AndyThomas i'm surprised all answers contain that

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
int x = 2, y = 3;
if ((x != 0) && (x < 10) && (y < 10))
{
    x++;
    y++;
    System.out.println(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It operates like a Nested if**. Why dont you check all condtion in the first if using a conditional AND. This way you would not need others.

**However its a good practice to have braces for each if. This way its more readable and less error prone when the code undergoes changes in the future**

Answer (score 0):

if () if() if() is just short hand
what it is really doing is

```
if(x != 0){
    if(x < 10){
        if(y < 1o){
            x++;
            y++;
            System.out.println(x, y);
        }else{}
    }else{}
}else{}
```

Comment: not including braces just means the next statement is considered as the body of the if statement. This is bad practice because what they could have done instead is just
    if( case && case && case){//do stuff}

Answer (score 0):

They're nested. Basically, the curly brace is optional for one line statement blocks. I assume `y < 1o` should be `y < 10`, also your `println` looks suspicious.

```
if (x != 0) {
  if (x < 10) {
    if (y < 10) {
      x++;
      y++;
      // System.out.println(x, y);
      System.out.println(Integer.toString(x) + " " + y);
    }
  }
}
```

You could certainly combine those into a single `if` (and even one line) with an `and` like

```
if (x != 0 && x < 10 && y < 10) {
  System.out.printf("%d %d%n", x++, y++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is similar to

```
if (x != 0) {
   if (x < 10) {
      if (y < 10) {
        x++;
        y++;
        System.out.println(x, y);
      }
   }
}
```

in an alternate way you can write

```
if((x != 0) && (x < 10) && (y < 10)) {
   x++;
   y++;
   System.out.println(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the && operator

```
int x = 2, y = 3;
if (x != 0 && x < 10 && y < 10) {
    x++;
    y++;
    System.out.println(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It operates like a nested if as said by Andy. Instead of using this write all the conditions in one if statement and use && operator.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java Logical Operators will resolve your problem.
**Click this link to learn more**
http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/45.html